# Retrieving unique combinations

Tags: r, unique, combinations

I have a data set which can be generated using the code below

```
df <- data.frame(Cust = c("Name1","Name1","Name1","Name1","Name1","Name2","Name2","Name2","Name2","Name2","Name2","Name2"),
                 Loc=c("Code1", "Code1", "Code2", "Code2", "Code3","Code1","Code1","Code1","Code1","Code1","Code2","Code2"), 
                 Date = c("Date1","Date1","Date2","Date2","Date2","Date1","Date1","Date2","Date2","Date3","Date2","Date2"), 
                 Var1 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","p", "q", "h", "i", "j"),
                 Var2 = c("r", "s", "u", "v", "w", "x","y", "a", "b", "z", "q", "p") )
```

It is sorted by Cust, Loc and then Date. The cols Var1 and Var2 are added just to show that there are other columns too in the dataset. I need to extract one row from the dataset for every unique combination of Cust, Loc and Date and create a new datatset of the extracted rows. The result will look like this below

[image]

I can do it by first sorting by Cust, Loc and Date and then scanning a full data set row by row and extracting the row when the Cust or Loc or Date changes.  But the actual data set is over 12 million rows and it would take too long.

Comment: So something like `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(Cust, Loc, Date) %>% summarise_all(first)`? Assuming you need to keep the details for `Var1` and `Var2` for one record? In this case the `first` values in `Var1` and `Var2` will be kept for each unique combination of `Cust`, `Loc` and `Date`.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks!