# Retrieving unique combinations with 'dominant' row

Tags: r, unique, subset

I have a dataset which can be generated with the following code

```
df <- data.frame(
        "Inv" = c("Name1", "Name1", "Name1", "Name1", "Name2", "Name2", "Name2", "Name3", "Name3", "Name3"), 
        "Loc"=c("Code1", "Code1", "Code2", "Code3", "Code2", "Code1", "Code2", "Code1", "Code2", "Code3")
    )
```

Dataset is sorted on `'Inv'`. I need to extract one row from each set of records with the same value for `'Inv'`.  The extracted row can either be the first row or the row with the dominant `'Loc'`. To further explain I have given the result and the reasoning for the choices below

Result

[image]

The logic is

1. The first row `"Name1", "Code1"` is extracted because the combination Name1:Code1 occurs twice in the set with `'Inv'` having value `"Name1"`.  The other combinations Name1:Code2 and Name1:Code3 occur only once each.  Therefore, Name1:Code1 is the 'dominant' case.
2. The second `"Name2", "Code2"` is extracted because the combination Name2:Code2 occurs twice in the set.
3. The third row `"Name3", "Code1"` is extracted because all three combinations Name3:Code1, Name3:Code2, Name3:Code3 occur only once each and since Name3:Code1 is the first row in the set, it is selected.

I can do this by sorting on `'Inv'` and stepping through the dataset row by row.  But this is a 12 million row dataset and it would take too much time.

Is there an easier and faster way of doing this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @akrun, I think the OP wants a slightly different answer as they are looking to keep the most frequently occurring `loc` values within each `Inv` group. I only realised this because I had given the same answer as you to this earlier question which is similarly worded -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/46482459/8475145

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this where we count the number of Loc in each Inv, keep only the Loc rows with a max value and take the first row for each remaining group.  Note, `arrange(rowname, .by_group = TRUE)` isn't necessary for your sample data but I think you will need this for the full dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse); 
df %>% as_tibble() %>% rownames_to_column() %>%
  group_by(Inv, Loc) %>% 
  mutate(Loc_count = n()) %>%
  group_by(Inv) %>%
  filter(Loc_count == max(Loc_count)) %>%
  arrange(rowname, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  summarise_all(first) %>%
  select(Inv, Loc)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      Inv    Loc
#>   <fctr> <fctr>
#> 1  Name1  Code1
#> 2  Name2  Code2
#> 3  Name3  Code3
```